# How to disable replacement and buffer in jQuery Inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

We have an input-field with a maxlength attribute. In this field, we only want to accept numbers, so we added jQuery.inputmask. (Must be IE8 compatible, so no `type="number"`).
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

<strike>See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QdLBT/</strike> (After the author fixed it, the fiddle does not illustrate the problem anymore)

The problem(s):
When entering text, and then using backspace, any text that "overflowed" will come back.

In addition, having the cursor in the middle of the input'ed text, and entering new numbers will replace the numbers already there (like having insert enabled on the keyboard).

This behavior was not there using inputmask v1.2.2, but is present using the latest v3.x branch. In v1.2.2 the mask respected the maxlength, i.e. just filtering out all that's not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the GitHub page of the project, and an hour later it was fixed.

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/547